# PHP Header New Page Using CSS Class

Tags: php, css, header

On my page i can click the below link and it opens a light box; this contains my login form. what i'm wanting is when i come from another page to this one the form opens without clicking.

```
<li><a class="cd-signin" href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
```

So from my splash screen im using

```
header( "refresh:2;url=Login.php#0" );
```

Is there anyway i can add class="cd-signin" to the header code?

I know its a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use JavaScript to click the link automatically on page load, if you really wanted it to open the form on page load. (note this is not necessarily the most ideal solution but it will do what you're asking):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('0').click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks, the form is only opened with  class="cd-signin" and href="#0", ive never used JavScript before; can this class be added into that ?

Comment: is it possible ?

Comment: Hi @Liam, sorry for the delay. You *could* in theory use document.getElementsByClassName('cd-signin').click(); but classes are meant to be for multiple elements and in theory it would click every element on the page. You would be better off assigning a unique ID to the element like: class="cd-signin" id="cd-signin" href="#0", then using my original snippet of document.getElementById('cd-signin').click();